# Sending dto with html file in Spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

My current controller is returning to an HTML page. I want to send some data (a DTO) which can be received at front end, like an ajax response (like it happens in ajax + RestController). But this is not a RestController, it is a normal @controller returning HTML. I don't know even if it is possible to send DTO with html. There isn't much code to look at. I am just looking for feasibility. Do let me know if additional info is required. Thanks

**Edit**

Here is some code for reference. login.html is the page I am returning to. I want to send some additional info with this return ( in the form of a DTO ).

```
@Controller
public class LoginUserController {

  @RequestMapping(value = {"/loginuser", "/loginuser?error"})
  public String login() {
    return "/login";
  }

}
```

Comment: return respose as html String and from ajax invoke  JqueryObject.html(respose.txt)

Comment: @NallaSrinivas Please see edit and suggest changes.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return view only i.e `jsp` in your case . You could put `DTO object` in modelMap and used inside `jsp` . Or simply if you want to return `JSON` only you could use [@ResponseBody](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html) .

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/loginuser", "/loginuser?error"})
  public String login(ModelMap model) {
   YourDTO dtoObject = // get DTO;
   model.put("dtoObject",dtoObject)
   return "/login";
 }

  class YourDTO {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    // getters setters 
  }
```

Inside login JSP you can use`dtoObject` .

```
     Name <c:out value="${dtoObject.name}" ></c:out>  // Using JSTL
```

Or In Html file

```
    <input type="text" id="name" value='${dtoObject.name}'/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're trying to build a spring boot web app, here is the bare minimum what you need to do:

1. Make sure your maven dependencies have **spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf** along with **spring-boot-starter-webapp** in the pom.xml

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Configure/write your controller like this :

   ```
   @Controller
   public class LoginUserController {

    @GetMapping(value = {"/loginuser", "/loginuser?error"})
    public String login( Model model) {
      model.addAttribute("message", "Aww snaps! something went wrong...");
      return "login";
    }

   }
   ```
3. Ensure you have **src/main/resources/templates/login.html** which may look like this:

   ```
      <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
      <head>
          <title>Login Page</title>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      </head>
      <body>
           <p th:text="${message}" />
      </body>
      </html>
   ```

You can use any other viewing technology of your choice instead of Thymeleaf. Basically the viewing technology  parses the HTML template, looks for expressions like

> th:text

to reslove the value of

> ${message}

with the data that you've put in the model in Controller.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use following code 

    @Controller
    public class LoginUserController {

     @GetMapping(value = {"/loginuser", "/loginuser?error"})
     public String login( Model model) {
       organizationDTO = organizationService.getOrganizationDTO(id);
        model.addAttribute("organizationDTO", organizationDTO);
       return "/login";
     }
}

and use below code in HTML page using JSTL

    <div class="row">
        <p class="col-md-4">${organizationDTO."your value"}</p>
    </div>

eg below 

    <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-2">Id</label>
            <p class="col-md-4">${organizationDTO.id}</p>
            <label class="col-md-2">Name</label>
            <p class="col-md-4">${organizationDTO.name}</p>
    </div>
```